# Displaying index.html page using @Controller | Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Having an issue with displaying the index.html webpage that I have created. The output that I keep receiving when heading over to localhost:8080 is the String value "index" and not the webpage itself. Images of the /templates directory & result given from localhost can be found below (hyperlinks)

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        @ResponseBody
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }
}
```

[template_directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTswQ.png)
[localhost:8080_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF7IM.png)

Comment: Try commenting out response body

Answer (score 10):

Remove `@ResponseBody` from your controller method addNewBooking(...). With `@ResponseBody` you tell Spring to map the result of your method to the HTTP response body and so your browser displays it as plain text (you need this if you want to develop RESTful APIs with Spring). As you are using Spring MVC, you want to return a view and therefore you don't need `@ResponseBody`.

**EDIT 1:** Detailed explanation of what I wrote.

With `Spring Web` you have two choices to write your app:

- Write a server-side rendered application with `JSPs`, `Thymeleaf templates`, `Freemaker templates` -> `Spring MVC` pattern
- Write a RESTful backend for e.g. a Single Page Application (like ReactJs or Angular) which gets its data from your RESTful backend

For choice 1 you annotate your controller with `@Controller` and offer several endpoints where your Spring application will respond with your server-side renderer template. All of your controller return a `String` which is the name of your template which you want to transfer to the browser. Spring will take the `String` name like `index` and will return e.g. the rendered `index.jsp` to the request. An example could look like the following:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }
}
```

For choice 2 you annotate your controller with `@RestController` **OR** you `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` together (technically `@RestController` is just a combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody). With this setup you tell Spring to use your controller method return type and parse it e.g. with Jackson to JSON and will put it in the HTTP body. If you access such an endpoint in your browser you get 
the JSON representation of your object. Look at the following example:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

        @RequestMapping("/persons")
        public List<Person> getPersons() {
            // ... some service calls/database access to get all persons
            return personList;
        }
}
```

The Person class:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   // getter and setter ...

}
```

If you now access `http://localhost:8080/persons` you could get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 1337
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter Parker",
    "age": 12
  }
]
```

To summarize the explanation: If you want to serve Views (HTML pages which are server side rendered) you have to use `@Controller` and your controller methods have to return the name of your template. If plan to build a RESTful application, use `@RestController` or the combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`together.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @YuriKhechoyan I updated my answer. I hope it will help you to understand the difference

Answer (score 5):

Like others have mentioned, the first thing you need to do is remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation from your controller method.

Secondly, The static content in your templates directory should be moved to
 `src/main/resources/static`. The `templates` directory is meant for serving content that needs to be rendered on the server side (for example Thymeleaf).

You can then serve the content directly from your controller.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: or @GetMapping("/index")
 public ModelAndView index() {
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
  String viewName = "index.html";
  modelAndView.setViewName(viewName);
  return modelAndView;
 }

Answer (score 2):

```
   @RequestMapping("/")
   @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

Remove @ResponseBody .

@RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations are used to bind the HTTP request/response body with a object in method parameter or return type.

@ResponseBody  : Spring will bind the return value to outgoing HTTP response body.

example

```
     @RequestMapping(value    = "/checkuser",
                     method   = RequestMethod.GET,  
                     produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
     @ResponseBody
     public Boolean checkValidateUser(@RequestParam Map<String, String>  
          requestParams){
          String userName = requestParams.get("username");
          String password = requestParams.get("password");
     return 
   userBL.checkValidateUser(userName.trim().toUpperCase(),password.trim());
  }
```

Images in src/main/resources/static/assets/images/
 Html pages in src/main/resources/templates

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use template engine like a thyemleaf, you must place ui files into a subfolder of `/src/main/resources` named `/public`, `/static` or `/resources`. Your `index.html` put into `/src/main/resources/public/index.html`

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```